# Update statement for multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-update

I have concerns with an update statement. 
The primary key of my table is composed of the following columns:
ReferencePiece, NumeroPhase, AncienPoste,DateStrategie, DateCadence, NomProgramme, VersionProgramme.
Here is my procedure:

```
UPDATE S
SET S.stock = T.Stock - T.NombrePiecesParAvion * T.CadenceProgramme
FROM SITUATIONS_Final_1 S
INNER JOIN SITUATIONS_Final_1 T ON S.ReferencePiece = T.ReferencePiece
    AND S.NumeroPhase = T.NumeroPhase
    AND S.AncienPoste = T.AncienPoste
    AND T.DateDebProduction < S.DateDebProduction
    AND T.stock = (
        SELECT min(T.stock)
        FROM SITUATIONS_Final_1 T
        )
WHERE S.DateDebProduction = (
        SELECT min(S.datedebproduction) AS 'date1'
        FROM SITUATIONS_Final_1 S
        INNER JOIN SITUATIONS_Final_1 T ON S.ReferencePiece = T.ReferencePiece
            AND S.NumeroPhase = T.NumeroPhase
            AND S.AncienPoste = T.AncienPoste
        WHERE S.datedebproduction > T.DateDebProduction
            AND T.stock = (
                SELECT min(T.stock)
                FROM SITUATIONS_Final_1 T
                )
        )
```

But actually, as there is no 'group by' on my update statement, It only takes into account the Min(stock) of all my references and do the update for the future dates.

I tried to do it as following but I'm sure it's much easier than that :

```
UPDATE S
SET S.stock = T.Stock - T.NombrePiecesParAvion * T.CadenceProgramme
FROM SITUATIONS_Final_1 S
INNER JOIN SITUATIONS_Final_1 T ON S.ReferencePiece = T.ReferencePiece
    AND S.NumeroPhase = T.NumeroPhase
    AND S.AncienPoste = T.AncienPoste
    AND T.DateDebProduction < S.DateDebProduction
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT referencepiece
        ,NumeroPhase
        ,AncienPoste
        ,DateStrategie
        ,nomprogramme
        ,versionprogramme
        ,datedebproduction
        ,min(stock) StockMini
    FROM SITUATIONS_Final_1
    GROUP BY ReferencePiece
        ,NumeroPhase
        ,AncienPoste
        ,DateStrategie
        ,nomprogramme
        ,versionprogramme
        ,DateDebProduction
    ) F ON F.ReferencePiece = T.ReferencePiece
    AND T.Stock = F.StockMini
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT referencepiece
        ,NumeroPhase
        ,AncienPoste
        ,DateStrategie
        ,nomprogramme
        ,versionprogramme
        ,min(datedebproduction) datemini
        ,stock
    FROM SITUATIONS_Final_1
    GROUP BY ReferencePiece
        ,NumeroPhase
        ,AncienPoste
        ,DateStrategie
        ,nomprogramme
        ,versionprogramme
        ,DateDebProduction
        ,stock
    ) Z ON F.ReferencePiece = Z.ReferencePiece
WHERE T.DateDebProduction = Z.datemini
    AND Z.datemini = F.DateDebProduction
    AND Z.Stock = F.StockMini
    AND T.ReferencePiece = Z.ReferencePiece
    AND S.datedebproduction > T.DateDebProduction
    AND T.stock = F.StockMini
    AND S.ReferencePiece = T.ReferencePiece
    AND T.ReferencePiece = F.ReferencePiece
    AND F.numerophase = Z.numerophase
    AND T.numerophase = Z.numerophase
    AND F.AncienPoste = Z.AncienPoste
    AND T.AncienPoste = Z.AncienPoste
    AND F.DateStrategie = Z.DateStrategie
    AND T.DateStrategie = Z.DateStrategie
    AND F.nomprogramme = Z.nomprogramme
    AND T.nomprogramme = Z.nomprogramme
    AND F.versionprogramme = Z.versionprogramme
    AND T.versionprogramme = Z.versionprogramme
    AND S.ReferencePiece = T.ReferencePiece
    AND S.NumeroPhase = T.NumeroPhase
    AND S.AncienPoste = T.AncienPoste
    AND S.nomprogramme = T.nomprogramme
    AND S.versionprogramme = T.versionprogramme
    AND S.DateStrategie = T.datestrategie
```

But it doesn't perform well: It updates the same rows (the sames dates). I need this procedure to do something like that:
Referencepiece=RefA  DateDebProduction='02/05/2015'  Stock=4   NbrePieces=2   CadenceProgramme=1
For the same reference and the next date The stock should be= 4-2*1=2...
 Actually, this procedure is contained on another one. It launches it 5 times so that I can be sure that It will update all my rows. If you could help me finding a better way to update all rows without launching my procedure many times it would be great.
Thank you very much

Comment: What version of SQL Server is this? Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: It's sql server 2012. Sorry, I thought my question was deleted and I asked a new one with a sample data. 
Thank you again !

Comment: I believe you can edit your question to add the sample data below. Also, if you could please format it to make it more readable, that would be wonderful! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of data:

ReferencePiece  NumeroPhase AncienPoste DateStrategie   Charge  NomProgramme    VersionProgramme    CadenceProgramme    DateCadence DateDebProduction   NombrePiecesParAvion    Stock

RefA001     10      114179A     02/05/2015  0.000   Z540 A      BGR         29.000          01/03/2015  01/03/2015      1.000           23.000
RefA001     10      114179A     02/05/2015  0.000   Z540 A      BGR         25.000          01/04/2015  01/04/2015      1.000           NULL
RefA001     10      114179A     02/05/2015  0.000   Z540 A      BGR         19.000          01/05/2015  01/05/2015      1.000           NULL
RefA001     10      114179A     02/05/2015  0.000   Z540 A      BGR         25.000          01/06/2015  01/06/2015      1.000           NULL
RefXY001    10      1MR704      02/05/2015  0.220   X220        RM          2.000           01/05/2015  01/05/2015      2.000           12.000
RefXY001    10      1MR704      02/05/2015  0.220   X220        RM          2.000           01/06/2015  01/06/2015      2.000           8.000
RefXY001    10      1MR704      02/05/2015  0.220   X220        RM          2.000           01/07/2015  01/07/2015      2.000           NULL
RefXY001    10      1MR704      02/05/2015  0.220   X220        RM          3.000           01/08/2015  01/08/2015      2.000           NULL